# Yii2: How to generate a JSON object with "grouped by" with an SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, json, yii2, grouping

I have a PostgreSQL query with the columns **address** and **price** like this. This is a simple example of the result of the SQL query:

[image: Just a simple example of the result of the SQL query]

I need to send this previous data in a JSON object and also **it has to be grouped by address**. So I need something like this:

```
[  
   {
      "address":"Elm Street 123",
      "name": {
         "John",
         "Maria",
         "George"
      }
   },
   {
      "address":"Piccadilly Street 456",
      "name": {
         "Robert"
      }
   },
]
```

I tried the next function to generated my desire JSON object but it doesn't generate the JSON object that I need:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
$persons = persons::find()
    ->select([
        'address',
        'name',
    ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

return $persons;
```

It generates this JSON object:

```
[  
   {
      "address":"Elm Street 123",
      "name": "John"
   },
   {
      "address":"Elm Street 123",
      "name": "Maria"
   },
   {
      "address":"Piccadilly Street 456",
      "name": "Robert"
   },
   {
      "address":"Elm Street 123",
      "name": "George"
   },
]
```

I use the Yii2 framework so I am looking for a solution in PHP. Maybe a SQL solution can work but I am not sure.

Comment: To my knowledge, you have to do that manually in php. There is no query (without being super complex) that 'automatically' does that for you. Just loop through it and group like addresses. I would start by creating an associative array then json_encode-ing it

Answer (score 0):

SQL (and yii2) cant handle this natively. so I rearrange array to make struct:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
$persons = persons::find()
        ->select([
            'address',
            'name',
        ])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
$result = [];
foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $address = $person['address'];
    if (!isset($result[$address])) {
        $result[$address] = ['address' => $address, 'name' => [],];
    }
    $result[$address]['name'][] = $person['name'];
}
return array_values($result);
```